# regarding a design of Train() function

Tags: pytorch

I once saw the following implementation of neural network. I am confused about the `model.train()` in the function of `Train()` . In class CNN_ForecastNet, I do not find the method of train,

```
class CNN_ForecastNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN_ForecastNet,self).__init__()
        self.conv1d = nn.Conv1d(3,64,kernel_size=1)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64*2,50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50,1)
        
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.conv1d(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = x.view(-1)
        #print('x size',x.size())
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        
        return x

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = CNN_ForecastNet().to(device)

def Train():
    
    running_loss = .0
    
    model.train()
    
    for idx, (inputs,labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        inputs = inputs.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        preds = model(inputs.float())
        loss = criterion(preds,labels.float())
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss
        
    train_loss = running_loss/len(train_loader)
    train_losses.append(train_loss.detach().numpy())
    
    print(f'train_loss {train_loss}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can find in the documentation, the [module train](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.train) function just set a flag in the model to `True` (you can use `model.eval()` to set the flag to `False`).

This flag is used by some layers for which the behavior changes in eval mode, most notably the dropout and batchnorm layers.